# XMLHttpRequest freezing Chrome extension

Tags: javascript, ajax, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, xmlhttprequest

I can't get XMLHttpRequest working in an asynchronous way.

Here is the code I'm using inside my `background.js` file

```
chrome.browserAction.onClicked.addListener(function(){
    if (!ready)
    {
        alert("Please wait, extension is not initialized yet. If you've just installed the extension, it can takes up to 10 minutes.");
    }
    else
    {
        game = urls[Math.floor(Math.random() * urls.length)];
        chrome.tabs.create({
            url: game
        });
    }
});

var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
xhr.open("GET", "myurl", true);
xhr.onreadystatechange = function() {
    if (xhr.readyState == 4) {
        // Some stuff
        ready = true;
        alert("Done");
    }
}
xhr.send();
```

This is working fine. The only problem is that the browserAction event is not fired until the XHR is done. If I try to click before, the event will be fired after `"Done"` is showed.

Am I doing something wrong ?

Here is the only interesting part of my manifest file

```
"background": {
    "scripts": ["background.js"]
},
```

Comment: Can you explain a bit more what you are trying to do ?

Comment: I have all the data stored for my extension on a server. So I want to retrieve those data with an asynchronous request. This work fine. The problem is that I want to display a message when the process isn't ready yet and I can't since the script seems to be frozen

Comment: Oh ok so the application can only become ready if you have performed that `GET` request?

Comment: Exactly ! I also use some caching system if the application have already be ran before but the very first time. The application seems to be frozen. At least, until the request is done. It acts like a synchronous call.

Comment: Any errors being produced by the `GET` request?

Comment: I just tested the `GET` out on `https://www.google.com` and everything appears to be working fine, I can post the code if you want.

Comment: No, the request is working and the app is working as expected when it's done. But while the request is pending, the app is freezing (ie. browser action is not sent)

Comment: It is actually working fine. Try to run it on a 15mo page that take few minutes to load. During the loading, the app is frozen.

Comment: But thats expected though right? Your app is actually *synchronous* to the `GET` request and therefore will only become ready once the request has been completed. If the request is still in progress then you do *not* want it to work so whats the issue?

Comment: Hmm Ok. I will try to explain you:

First case: App is not loaded.

I want to run an asynchronous request to load the current app data. The app would show the cached data if any, otherwise, a message saying that the request is pending

Actually, the app is frozen.

Second case, the app is loaded and the request is done. Then I want to use the new data. This is actually working perfectly.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/47259/discussion-between-1337holiday-and-masadow)